# Every time I open up a new tab all the posts are cleared in php

Tags: php

Every time I open up a new tab all the posts are cleared and everything is refreshed.

I'm trying to make a textboard/forum from scratch. I have learned how to more than one post.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="https://wikiscams.org/form.php" method="post">
            <?php if(!empty($_POST['user'])){
            foreach ($_POST['user'] as $key => $value) { ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="user[]" value="<?=$value?>">
            <?php }
            } ?>
            <input type="text" name="user[]" placeholder="Anon">
            <textarea cols="48" rows="4"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" name="submit">
            
        </form>
    </body>
</html>

<?php 
        if(!empty($_POST['user'])){
            foreach($_POST['user'] as $key => $user){
                echo $user."<br />";
            }
        }
?>
```

What should I do?

Comment: Do you store the data anywhere? The content of POST requests is not persisted between different tabs of your browser

Answer (score 0):

You are using POST and POST Data is not persist, that's mean it will be posted once to the page where you want and after which it will be destroy. So you need to save it in a file or in DB or in session just like below

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="user[]" placeholder="Anon">
    <textarea cols="48" rows="4"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
if(!empty($_POST['user'])){
    if(isset($_SESSION['user']))
        $_SESSION['user']=array_merge($_SESSION['user'],$_POST["user"]);
    else
        $_SESSION['user']=$_POST["user"];
}


if(!empty($_SESSION['user'])){
    foreach($_SESSION['user'] as $key => $user){
        echo $user."<br />";
    }
}
?>
```

I have rewrite your code just to define how it will be work..
But it is saving the data in server session so whenever session will be expired your all data will be deleted or destroyed so you need to save / insert your data in a file or DB